# Building time series from lists in R?

Tags: r, list, time-series, lapply

Hi I am trying to make a list of time-series objects by applying ts() function to the list of dataframes that I have. My list of dataframes is called whisk.basic.lst and it contain 69 dataframes. I am showing how it look like below:

```
    > str(whisk.basic.lst)
 $ SI_VALUES_IMV_EU28_INTRA  :List of 12
  ..$ 220830  : num [1:74] 218674 255317 327377 363219 335267 ...
  ..$ 22083011: num [1:74] 9363 10129 19672 20631 10403 ...
  ..$ 22083019: num [1:74] 0 1978 0 0 7116 ...
  ..$ 22083030: num [1:74] 3837 15684 14588 20487 30870 ...
  ..$ 22083041: num [1:74] 18979 5123 7176 36842 9390 ...
  ..$ 22083049: num [1:74] 688 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083061: num [1:74] 0 0 3452 4225 96 ...
  ..$ 22083069: num [1:74] 0 0 0 40 0 0 7520 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083071: num [1:74] 139915 204803 256095 218105 185088 ...
  ..$ 22083079: num [1:74] 0 3219 0 0 3381 ...
  ..$ 22083082: num [1:74] 45892 14381 26394 62889 88527 ...
  ..$ 22083088: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 396 0 0 0 642 105 ...
 $ SK_VALUES_IMV_EU28_EXTRA  :List of 11
  ..$ 220830  : num [1:74] 7155 12311 237 2705 7419 ...
  ..$ 22083011: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 35 0 0 0 122 0 ...
  ..$ 22083019: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083030: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 935 235 732 0 669 0 ...
  ..$ 22083041: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 2603 ...
  ..$ 22083049: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083061: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083071: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 27 0 546 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083079: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083082: num [1:74] 7155 12311 237 2705 3819 ...
  ..$ 22083088: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SK_VALUES_IMV_EU28_INTRA  :List of 11
  ..$ 220830  : num [1:74] 380007 459653 155033 205879 297446 ...
  ..$ 22083011: num [1:74] 26772 68577 8585 24567 17996 ...
  ..$ 22083019: num [1:74] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ 22083030: num [1:74] 60521 15068 1830 9788 5557 ...
  ..$ 22083041: num [1:74] 110461 71551 66317 47354 46776 ...
  ..$ 22083049: num [1:74] 100 19718 4115 201 201 ...
  ..$ 22083061: num [1:74] 0 29706 0 0 8177 ...
  ..$ 22083071: num [1:74] 418 21760 3138 68164 46300 ...
  ..$ 22083079: num [1:74] 0 738 0 738 2213 ...
  ..$ 22083082: num [1:74] 181487 186179 68737 53360 170226 ...
  ..$ 22083088: num [1:74] 248 46356 2311 1707 0 ...

Ts.whisk.lst <- lapply(whisk.basic.lst, function(x) ts(x, frequency= 12, start=c(2010,1)))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error in ts(x, frequency = 12, start = c(2010, 1)) : 
  'ts' object must have one or more observations
Called from: ts(x, frequency = 12, start = c(2010, 1))
```

I have been creating time series from my dataframes without any problem in the past. But since I created a list of these dataframes, I have run into this problem. Does anyone know why?

Comment: It seems like you have a list of lists, rather than a list of data.frames; but regardless, I think the error is caused by one or more empty lists in `whisk.basic.lst`. What does `all(lengths(whisk.basic.lst) > 0)` return?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and cut down your data to the minimum needed to illustrate the eror.  See `?dput` and [mcve]

Comment: @nrussell. I started with a list of dataframes and it seems somewhere in the middle I got to a list of lists. Anyway, i am getting FLASE as the response to your code.

Comment: The `FALSE` indicates you have at least one empty list, which is causing the error. Try using `whisk.basic.lst[lengths(whisk.basic.lst) > 0]` as your first argument to `sapply` instead.

Comment: Thanks @nrussell. You were right. I applied such filter at the very early stage and removed some of the dataframes and columns with too many NA or zeros but apparently some of them were persistent.